# LL(1) parsing table construction

Tags: compilers, parsers

i have the following CFG

```
E -> ABC
A-> a|Cb|epsilon
B-> c|xA|epsilon
C-> y|z
```

and the First of the Non-Terminal :

```
First(E) = {a,y,z,epsilon}
Frist(A) = { a,y,z,epsilon}
First(B) = { c,x,epsilon }
First(C) = {y,z}
```

the follow of Non-Terminal :

```
follow(E)={$}
follow(A)={c,x,y,z}
follow(B)={y,z}
follow(C)={b,$}
```

my problem is how to construct the parsing table , i constructed the table and i got the following , but i think there is something missing/mistake in the table

```
    x    a    b    c    y    z    $
------------------------------------
E       ABC            ABC  ABC  epsilon
A eps.   a        eps. Cb   Cb           
B  xA              c   eps.  eps.        
C                       y     z
```

i hope the table is clear ,

Note : in the row A i got epsilon with both Cb in y And Cb in z , but i did not write it in the table , **is that mean the grammer is not LL(1) ??**

thank you!

Comment: FIRST(E) includes c and x, but not epsilon (why?)

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the general case.
Given a production of a grammar, let's say A -> α where α is a general string, to compute the LL(1) parsing table T the algorithm says:

```
foreach(A -> α in the grammar):
  write A -> α in T[A,b], ∀  b ∈ first(α);
  if ( ℇ ∈ first(α) ):
     write A -> α in T[A,x], ∀ x ∈ follow(A);
```

**If at the end of the algorithm you have any cell in the table T with more than one entry then the grammar is not LL(1)**, as in your case.
To run this algorithm you need to compute the set of firsts and follow of a symbol. I see you did right the follows sets, but you mistake in the firsts set of E. So here is the algorithm to compute the firsts set of a symbol X:

```
if(X is a terminal symbol):
  first(X) = X;
  break;
if (X -> ℇ ∈ productions of the grammar):
  first(X).add({ ℇ });
foreach(X -> Y1....Yn ∈ productions of the grammar):
  j = 1;
  while (j <= n):
    first(X).add({ b }), ∀ b ∈ first(Yj) ;
    if ( ℇ ∈ first(Yj)):
       j ++;
    else:
       break;
if(j = n+1):
  first(X).add({ ℇ });
```

So going back to your example:

```
First(E) = {a,y,z,c,x}
```

and in the table:

```
T[E,$] = E -> ABC
```

Comment: why we need to do -   if ( ℇ ∈ first(α) ):
     write A -> α in T[A,x], ∀ x ∈ follow(A)