# How to generate LL(1) parse table

Tags: parsers

Given the following grammar:

```
S -> A a
A -> B D
B -> b
B -> ε
D -> d
D -> ε
```

first would be:

```
B: {b,ε}
D: {d,ε}
A: {b,ε,d}
S: {b,ε,d,a}
```

and follow would be:

```
S: {$}
A: {a}
B: {d,a}
D: {a}
```

The LL(1) parse table should be easy to build. According to [LL(1) parsing table construction](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66927/ll1-parsing-table-construction) I can simply follow this algorithm:

```
foreach(A -> α in the grammar):
  write A -> α in T[A,b], ∀  b ∈ first(α);
  if ( ℇ ∈ first(α) ):
     write A -> α in T[A,x], ∀ x ∈ follow(A);
```

However, this would leave T[S,a] and T[A,d] blank, so "a" and "d a" could not be parsed:

```
row S:
  column  b -> S -> A a
  column  d -> S -> A a
  column  $ -> S -> A a
row A:
  column  b -> A -> B D
  column  a -> A -> B D
row B:
  column  b -> B -> b
  column  d -> B -> ε
  column  a -> B -> ε
row D:
  column  d -> D -> d
  column  a -> D -> ε
```

When I use a tool like this: http://jsmachines.sourceforge.net/machines/ll1.html values for T[S,a] and T[A,d] are generated. Am I using a wrong algorithm for generating the parse table, is the grammar not LL1 or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: $a$ is in $first(S)$ and $d$ is in $first(A)$. Why would the corresponding entries be blank?

Comment: @rici According to the formula from the linked SE page, only every $b$ in $first(α)$ should be added to $T[A,b]$, so $T[A,d]$ would be blank because $d$ is not in $first(B)$

Comment: For the production $A\to BD$, $\alpha$ is $BD$, and $first(\alpha)$ is $first(BD)$, not $first(B)$. And $d$ most certainly is in $first(BD)$.

Comment: @rici ah see, that's where I went wrong. Thank you!